# ECS unable to connect to AWS ElastiCache

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, amazon-elasticache

I have a dockerised web app that uses aws elasticache but while trying to deploy it on ECS I can't seem t connect to the elasticache.
I have added the ECS security group to elasticache security group but it still doesn't work.
I tried to curl the URL from instance but got response as :

- Could not resolve host: XXX.cache.amazonaws.com
- Closing connection 0
  curl: (6) Could not resolve host: XXX.cache.amazonaws.com

Comment: Are they both in the same VPC? Does the VPC have DNS enabled?

Comment: Yes they both are in the same VPC i have even added the security groups. Further this app was previously deployed on ebs i am just moving it to docker and getting problems with elasticache